# Running VB script from a C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, vbscript, windows-services

I have a Windows Service written in C# which simply tries to execute a VB script when a file is dropped into a watched folder.  While the script will launch fine if I simply double click it it does not seem to be started by the Service.  You will see in the code below that I am writing to a log along the way and it seems as though it thinks it's trying to start cscript and execute the script but weirdly after 30 seconds it just terminates with exit code 0.

```
        public static void ExecVB_Script(string scriptpath)
    {
        try
        {
            WriteErrorLog("Execute VB instruction received.  Attempting to run VB script " + scriptpath);
            if (!File.Exists(scriptpath))
            {
                WriteErrorLog("Error: VB script execution Failed. Cannot find script " + scriptpath);
            }
            else
            {

                WriteErrorLog("Starting cscript.exe");
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = @"cscript.exe";
                startInfo.WorkingDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VBScriptExecPath"];
                WriteErrorLog("Working Directory is: " + startInfo.WorkingDirectory.ToString());
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@" //B //Nologo " + scriptpath);
                WriteErrorLog("Arguements passed: "+ startInfo.Arguments);
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                WriteErrorLog("Attempting to execute VB script");
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
                WriteErrorLog("cscript.exe has finished");
                WriteErrorLog(process.ExitCode.ToString());

            }
        }
```

Output from log file.

```
28/01/2015 16:52:46: Execute VB instruction received.  Attempting to run VB script D:\utils\UPLOAD.vbs
28/01/2015 16:52:46: Starting cscript.exe
28/01/2015 16:52:46: Working Directory is: D:\utils\
28/01/2015 16:52:46: Arguements passed:  //B //Nologo D:\utils\UPLOAD.vbs
28/01/2015 16:52:46: Attempting to execute VB script
28/01/2015 16:53:16: cscript.exe has finished
28/01/2015 16:53:16: 0
```

The service is running as the local admin and I am also logged in as the local admin so it seems as though it's unlikely that this is an access or permissions issue.  Also, when the VB script is executed manually it also writes a text log but when when trigger by the C# Windows Service no log is written to which suggests that the VB script has not been executed at all.

Comment: Maybe try wscript.exe without the //B and the CreateNoWindow for debugging to see if an error is produced.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem ? If yes how? ;)

Comment: I was never able to get this to work properly so I ended up writing what the VB script did in c#